# HTML: Inline block doesn't work for just one table

Tags: html, display, ccss

I'm REALLY new to html, and I'm trying to create a html set of tables, I am using display : inline block and it works the way I want, to put some tables next to the others... but when I put just one table it doesnt shows the borders of the table. The code is the following:

```css
        table {
               border: 1px solid black;
               border-collapse:collapse;
               display: inline-block;
              }
        h2.headertekst {
               text-align: center;
               color : white;
               font-family: verdana
               }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<body bgcolor="#3377ff">
<h2 class = "headertekst">Mis Pokemons Favoritos</h2>
<table bgcolor="#e52b50">
<tr>
<th rowspan="4">
<img src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/shiny/1.png">
</th>
<td style="color: white">Nombre: Bulbasaur</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: white">Peso: 69</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td style="color: white">Altura: 10</td>
</tr>  
<tr>
<td style="color: white">Expreriencia Base: 64</td>
</tr>   
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

and the rest is just the information on the cells

Comment: share complete code, i think some of code is missing

Comment: Please post your full code so we can see the issue.

Comment: Just did, thank you guys

Answer (score 0):

Why are you trying to do it inline? I would suggest using float:right on the tables

Comment: Because I will add a lot more of tables, so I need them to be ordered. It seems like float:right puts the table on the right part of the page

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add borders inside your tables you have to style td and th elements:

```
table td, table th {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Or if you need to add only vertical line:

```
table td, table th { border-left:1px solid black; }
```